# How to get a music player with circular progress bar and play button in center?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want an audio player app just like this image:

[image]

I'm playing the audio using dependency injection on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there's some external nuget like [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/gauges) and [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/circular-gauge) that provides API for you to implement a circular gauge, so you can create your audio player button in Xamarin.

If you want to implement that feature yourself, you can create your own layouts.
Let the total length of the audio is `total` and the length played already is `played`.

> Approach 1:

Let's call this layout `Base`:

- When the audio bar is less than or equal to 50% filled, create a blue circle base `B`.  Cover the left half of `B` with a gray semicircle `G1` and the right half of `B` with another gray semicircle `G2`.  Then Rotate `G2` by `360.0 * played / total`.
- When the audio bar is more than 50% filled, create a gray circle base `G` instead.  Cover the right half of `G` with a blue semicircle `B1` and the right half of `G` again with another blue semicircle `B2`.  Then Rotate `B2` by `360.0 * played / total - 180.0`

Finally put a play/pause icon on top of a smaller white circle on top of `Base` to create your final audio player button.

> Approach 2:

You can use [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/) in Xamarin.Forms to draw circles and arcs.  You can create your audio play button by drawing a gray arc and a blue arc with length according to `played` and `total`.  They have a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/arcs#the-angle-arc) on how to use SkiaSharp.

Comment: Can u explain me this in terms of code that would be really helpful.